# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (xcode 7)

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I updated my xcode 6.4 to xcode 7 (swift 2) and now I'm getting this error in my swift project. After few tries i found out it was happening because of

```
func containerView() -> UIView {
    return self.view
}
```

which is a protocol of **UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext** , if i remove that function then it says my ViewController does not conform to this protocol **UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext** . xcode 7 is suggesting me to change the function to

```
func containerView() -> UIView? {
    return self.view
}
```

and after that it suggests me to delete the question mark. I don't really understand what to do here, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do something illegal. Here are the first two sentences of the documentation on UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext:

> An object that conforms to the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext protocol provides information about an in-progress view controller transition. *Do not adopt this protocol in your own classes.*

The italics are mine. But that's to emphasize the rule that I think you are attempting to violate. You cannot possibly *be* a UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext. This is something that the runtime provides, not you.

Comment: this is what it says in errors **warning: result of 'containerView()' has different optionality than expected by protocol 'UIViewControllerContextTransitioning'
    func containerView() -> UIView {
         ^
                                  ?
UIKit.UIViewControllerContextTransitioning:3:14: note: requirement 'containerView()' declared here
  @objc func containerView() -> UIView?
             ^
**
and this is the code https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/ECSwiftSlidingViewController/blob/master/ECSwiftSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController.swift line 770

Comment: Did you read my answer? You have apparently tried to make your view controller adopt the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext protocol. You can't do that.

Comment: And the same is true for UIViewControllerContextTransitioning. The docs say: "The UIViewControllerContextTransitioning protocol’s methods provide contextual information for transition animations between view controllers. _Do not adopt this protocol in your own classes_."

Comment: So i need to remove UIViewControllerContextTransitioning delegate?

Comment: I didn't say anything about the _delegate_. You have not shown enough code, but it sounds like you are saying something like `class ViewController : UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext` and I'm saying you can't say that. But that's just a guess, because you didn't show enough code. If you want to show some surrounding code, that would be great.

Comment: this is the code I'm using https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/ECSwiftSlidingViewController/blob/master/ECSwiftSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController.swift (line 770)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90058/discussion-between-ankit-and-matt).

Comment: did you see the code? I'm still struggling with this.